# How to checkpoint using CRIU on ubuntu 14?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I tried to install CRIU in ubuntu 14.04 Desktop.

When I used

```
$ sudo ./criu check
```

, it showed

```
Error (cr-check.c:268): fdinfo doesn't contain the mnt_id field
```

And when I tried to checkpoint joomla or xampp using

```
$sudo ./criu dump -D checkpoint -t 4761
```

, it shows

```
Error (proc_parse.c:502): Can't open 4761/stat on procfs: No such file or directory
```

CRIU: 
Verison: criu-1.3-rc1
Location: /home/criu-1.3-rc1/

How should I do to solve the problems?

Comment: Do you have the needed kernel options enabled?  CRIU depends on several non-standard options like `CONFIG_CHECKPOINT_RESTORE` or `CONFIG_MEM_SOFT_DIRTY`.  Try running without arguments (IIRC), this should tell you whether your kernel supports the needed features.

Answer (score 0):

you should use following line in non-custom kernels:

```
$ sudo ./criu check --ms
```

Are you sure that you have a thread with pid 4761? Also, you should have a `checkpoint` directory in your `criu` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile your kernel with required for CRIU options http://criu.org/Installation